# Edit & delete data table by id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table diklat, how to edit and delete table data based on each id. I have a table diklat, how to edit and delete table data based on each id. When I try, the data is not successfully edited

**Database Table diklat**

[image: Database Table diklat]

**Table history diklat**

[image: Table history diklat]

**View Edit**

```
<form action="<?= base_url('diklat'); ?>" method="post">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Jenis Kegiatan</th>
                <th>Nama Kegiatan</th>
                <th>Penyelenggara</th>
                <th>Tempat</th>
                <th>Tanggal</th>
                <th>Sertifikat</th>
                <th>Aksi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $no = 0;
            foreach ($data as $diklat) :
                $no++;
                $jenisDiklat     = $diklat['jenis_diklat'];
                $namaDiklat        = $diklat['nama_diklat'];
                $penyelenggara     = $diklat['penyelenggara'];
                $tempatDiklat     = $diklat['tempat_diklat'];
                $waktuDiklat    = $diklat['waktu_diklat'];
                $sertifikat     = $diklat['sertifikat'];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $namaDiklat; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $jenisDiklat; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $penyelenggara; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tempatDiklat; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $waktuDiklat; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?= base_url('diklat/viewPdf' . $diklat['id_diklat']); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $sertifikat; ?></a></td>
                    <td><a href="<?= base_url('diklat/edit'); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
                        <a href="<?= base_url('diklat/delete' . $diklat['id_diklat']); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Hapus</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Function Controller Edit**

```
public function edit()
{
   $data['title'] = 'Edit Data Pelatihan & Seminar';
   $data['akun'] = $this->db->get_where('akun', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
   $data['diklat'] = $this->db->get_where('diklat', ['id_diklat'])->row_array();

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_namadiklat', 'nama_diklat', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Nama Diklat Belum Diisi!']);
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_penyelenggara', 'penyelenggara', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Penyelenggara Diklat Harus Diisi!']);
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_tempatdiklat', 'tempat_diklat', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Tempat Diklat Harus Diisi!']);

   if ($this->form_validation->run() ==  false)
   {
      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/sidebarmenu', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/top_bar', $data);
      $this->load->view('diklat/edit');
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
   }else {
      $id          = $this->input->post('id_diklat');
      $nama_diklat   = $this->input->post('f_namadiklat');
      $jenis_diklat  = $this->input->post('f_jenisdiklat');
      $penyelenggara     = $this->input->post('f_penyelenggara');
      $tempat_diklat     = $this->input->post('f_tempatdiklat');
      $waktu_diklat  = $this->input->post('tgl_diklat');

      $this->db->set('nama_diklat', $nama_diklat);
      $this->db->set('jenis_diklat', $jenis_diklat);
      $this->db->set('penyelenggara', $penyelenggara);
      $this->db->set('tempat_diklat', $tempat_diklat);
      $this->db->set('waktu_diklat', $waktu_diklat);

      //utk mengecek jika gambar yg di upload ada
      $upload_data = $_FILES['sertifikat']['name'];

      if ($upload_data) {
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
         $config['max_size'] = '2048';
         $config['upload_path'] = './assets/doc/sertifikat/';

         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ($this->upload->do_upload('sertifikat')) {
            $old_data = $data['diklat']['sertifikat'];
            if ($old_data != 'default.jpg') {
               unlink(FCPATH . 'assets/doc/sertifikat/' . $old_data);
            }

            $new_sertifikat = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $this->db->set('sertifikat', $new_sertifikat);
         } else {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
         }
      }

      $this->db->where('id_diklat', $id);
      $this->db->update('diklat');

      $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      Data Diklat Berhasil di Update</div>');
      redirect('diklat');
   }
}
```

**function delete controller**

```php
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('diklat_m');
    $where = array('id_diklat' => $id);
    $this->diklat_m->delete_data($where, 'diklat');
    redirect('diklat');
}
```

**function model delete_data**

```php
function delete_data($table, $where)
{
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->delete($table);
}
```

I have a table diklat, how to edit and delete table data based on each id.

When I try, the data is not successfully edited

Comment: What do you think this line will exactly do ? `<a href="<?= base_url('diklat/delete'.$diklat['id_diklat']); ?>"` ? (do you think you are missing a `/` ?)

Answer (score 0):

Delete Data is very simple
In table add `<a>` before and after of delete option
Ex: **`<a href="delete.php?id=<?=$id?>">Delete</a>`**

In variable $id store current data $id

delete.php Add following code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=$_GET['id']";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

For Edit option do same thing
ex: `<a href="edit.php?id=<?=$id?>">Edit</a>`

In edit.php add code for select one data from database by using where condition in query and print it in html form in input types and at the end add update button
Form action should be update.php
in update.php write update sql query

Note: Add input type hidden in edit.php
Ex: `<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="id" value=<?=$_GET['id']?>>`
and get it in update.php using `$_GET['id]`.

Comment: Please share your full code and database table export file if still facing issue (share code on this mail id: jay@oceanmnc.com)

Comment: thank you. But its not working

Comment: I use framework Codeigniter 3 in my code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).